# Android Gridview without Image Adaptor

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a blank linear list, I've got a list of images that will load dynamically (from url's, working).

I need to display the images in a grid (like when you access facebook photo gallery).

I can't use XML for obvious reasons, I've got the images displaying just they are on-top of each other and really small.

Also is it possible to set them to a percentage of the screen size easy? (So the list looks the same on all devices)

Here's the code so far:

```
private void Display()
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading Photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    //Get width of the image.
    int imageWidth = (int)getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 3;
    LayoutParams gp = new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int)imageWidth);

    //Placeholders
    for(int _i = 0; _i < _noOfPhotos; _i++)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(gp);

        _imageViewArray.add(imageView);
        this.addContentView(_imageViewArray.get(_i), gp);
    }

    //Set URL

    //UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, _userGallery.get(_i).getPicture());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html), that is exactly for this usecase.

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:numColumns="3" />
```

you can get the width of each ImageView with

```
float width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 3;
mLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
            GridView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            (int)width); // set the width as height for quadratic images
```

and then, in your ListAdapter for the GridView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context); // need to check convertView
    imageView.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));
    imageView.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm getting the error : error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix on the first xml bit :-/

Comment: this xml snippet is ment to add into a LinearLayout for example. if you wanna us it by itself add the android namespace attribute xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: its not so complicated. you just need to get used to the principle of ListAdapters. this is very commonly used in android development (also for all ListViews). here is a simple example for GridView http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I'm stuck, can you make this simpler or?

Comment: Can I do this without an image adaptor?

Comment: you can use an ArrayAdapter if you like. you don't need a separate class for that in simple cases. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Problem is I cannot access any adaptors, I just need to go though a loop displaying each image in turn (as placeholders and clickables). Problem is the images arn't displaying as a list, their all in one place.

Comment: if that is the case, i think your design is fundamentally wrong and you do not understand how the android UI elements work. but if you really wanna do it this way you have to remember that the base layout used in an activity is the FrameLayout. you should check it's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems like Android is painful (especially the xml parts) but I'll keep on trucking almost out of this xml crap and then back to my gaming part :-). Thanks.

Comment: it is just painful as long as you use it wrong. once you get used to the android paradigms, it becomes easy. you should go over some sample apps to learn how it works.

Comment: The problem is this has to load URL dynamically from when each imageview is seen (as not to load too many at once), this also loads from facebook, the facebook SDK is really crap so I've got to create the images within a fbmanager class for display :-(. (Can't pass them as an array because they need to reload once limited is reached). Wish I could just use a for loop setting each image next to one another simply :-/

Comment: you have to set a default local image first and then load the remote images in the background with an AsyncTask. google for that and you will find tons of examples.